# Angular 2 order of loading content

Tags: angularjs, components, router

With Angular 2 the content is loading in the "wrong" order.

I am new to Angular 2 and decided to start really simple.

I expect to see the menu.ts content before the First.component.ts "Hello world" content. But it seems the content from the router loads before the content of the app.compontent. When I put the @Router at the bottom Typescript says "Declaration expected" so that is not a solution either.

Is there really no other way then placing the menu at each router request?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { FirstComponent } from './Components/FirstComponent/FirstComponent';

@Routes([
    {
        path: '/',
        component: FirstComponent // Hello world, loads before the component below?!
    }
])

@Component({
    'directives': [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    'selector': 'app',
    'templateUrl': `/templates/FirstComponent.menu`
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor () {}

    opened: Boolean = true;
    toggle () {
      this.opened = !this.opened;
    }
}
```

**menu.ts**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']"></a><router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top affix-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" (click)="toggle()">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas clearfix" [ngClass]="{in: opened}" id="navbar-main-menu">
  <nav class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navmenu clearfix" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item2">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**First.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    'selector': 'app',
    'template': `Hello World!`
})

export class FirstComponent { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` below the menu